# Gitlab - Login when enable Two-Factor Authentication on window

Tags: gitlab, two-factor-authentication

I have enable Two-Factor Authen in gitlab, everytime I do `git push` a box below show and I cannot login, no input for enter 2FA code. Now I turn 2FA off for continue work.

How to login when enable Two-Factor Authen in gitlab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the [guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html#recovery-codes):

```
Log in to your GitLab account.
Go to your Profile Settings.
Go to Access Tokens.
Choose a name and expiry date for the token.
Click on Create Personal Access Token.
Save the personal access token somewhere safe.
```